# How to add category option to shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm new to creating wordpress shortcodes and have one just about working the way I want. Missing something specific. Currently I am able to put the following on any page - [children] and it pulls a query of all posts from the custom post type "children" I would like to add the option to add the category id within the shortcode - something like [children category="8"] Here is the code I have so far:

```
add_shortcode( 'children', 'display_custom_post_type' );

function display_custom_post_type(){
    $args = array(
'post_type' => 'children',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    $string = '';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            $string .= '<div id="childWrapper"><div id="childImage"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a></div><div style="clear: both;"></div><div id="childName">' . get_the_title() . '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $string;
}
```

Secondary - is it possible for it to show posts in multiple categories, but only where the posts are in each of the categories. For example showing a list of children, who fall under a category for critical care and surgery needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use parameterized [shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84450/multiple-parameters-for-a-shortcode), you can pass category attributes as the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer [Shortcode function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes) from WordPress Codex. Assuming your taxonomy name is **category**, I made some changes in your current code it should work as per your requirements.

```
/**
 *  [children category="5,7,8"]
 */
add_shortcode( 'children' , 'display_custom_post_type' );

function display_custom_post_type($atts) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => ''
    ), $atts );

  //If category is multiple: 8,9,3
  $categories  = explode(',' , $atts['category']);

    $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'children',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'orderby'       => 'title',
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page'=> -1,
            'tax_query'     => array( array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                'field'     => 'term_id',
                                'terms'     => $categories
                            ) )
        );

        $string = '';
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
            return false;
        }

        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            $string .= '<div id="childWrapper"><div id="childImage"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a></div><div style="clear: both;"></div><div id="childName">' . get_the_title() . '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        return $string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jignesh - so far it works using the following shortcode in a page: [children category=8] but if I try to add more then one category, it does not work - for example [children category=8,17] results in no listings

Comment: for some reason the shortcode is not working after the change, unless I'm writing the shortcode wrong. I have tried the following: [children category=8,17] and [children category="8,17"] and [children category='8,17']

Comment: still trying to resolve the multi category issue not pulling with any of the following shortcakes: [children category=8,17] and [children category="8,17"] and [children category='8,17'] - when using these no details show up on the page, but if I go with just one category it works - for example [children category=8] works fine

Comment: It works on all the shortcodes you wrote. I tried on my own website. make sure your taxonomy is correct.

Comment: It's working now, but I have an additional question. What I am trying to have it do is only pull posts which meet each one of the category IDs. Another words I have the following categories setup English, In-Home, Critical Care and Surgery needed. I want the shortcode to only pull a post when it meets all of the IDs specific. So I might have a shortcode with the English and In-Home category, which only should show children who have both of those categories. Another shortcode would pull English and Critical Care and so on.

Comment: First of all, accept the answer so that it can be helpful to others and they can know it's working and to display only posts that having these categories, add `'operator'   => 'AND',` to tax_query array.

Comment: how would you add a response of something like "no posts" if nothing meets the query?

Comment: you need to put while loop inside if condition and in else part you can return your desired response.